# pl/sql function return multiple columns

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

For example I have a query

```
select (select 1 from dual) res1
       , (select 2 from dual) res2
       , (select 3 from dual) res3 
from dual;
```

Result:

```
res1 res2 res3
---- ---- ----
   1    2    3
```

I want to create function with loop from 1 to 3 which will return me same result, 3 columns in 1 row

```
 FOR i IN 1..3 LOOP

 END LOOP;
```

What should be in function body to achieve goal?
I know I can use PIVOT to get this result in select query, but parameter of function is dynamic (numberFrom(1) and numberTo(3)), because of it I need loop

Pseudocode:
Inside loop I have select query, which uses parameters in loop. And result of select should be a new column in final result

```
FOR i IN 1..3 LOOP
   select i from dual;
END Loop;
```

I want this:

[image]

Not this:

[image]

I can pass any integers as parameters. So if I pass 3 and 8 I should qet 3,4,5,6,7,8

Comment: What is the return type of the function? (Or is that your question?)

Comment: I think it should be datatable with 1 row. I'm new in plsql and sorry for my mistakes in question. I want to get exactly the same result after function call as first query in my question. One person said what in plsql I should use function for such thing and procedure is used for insert only.

Comment: I need to get not a single value, I want to get result with only one row and multiple columns. Function should give me a list of integers between parameter1=1 and parameter2=3 listed in a single row, so each integer is a new column and it should look like 1 2 3

Comment: Are you saying you will have more than just 1, 2, and 3? You might also have 4, 5, etc... on the same row?

Comment: I'm not sure what a datatable is. You will need to define a suitable type, either in a package or in SQL using `create type xxx as object (..)`. A function needs to return a specific type, or else maybe [`anydatatype`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/t_anydat.htm) or XML.

Comment: Bob, yes, I can pass any integers as parameters. So if I pass 3 and 8 I should het 3,4,5,6,7,8.

Comment: This is really bad practice, but can you return a varchar2 of CSVs, and have the program using the function unstring them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "I can pass any integers as parameters. So if I pass 3 and 8 I should get 3,4,5,6,7,8"

You need Dynamic SQL for this.

```
create or replace function get_numbers 
   ( p_start in number, p_end in number )
    return sys_refcursor
is
    v_stmt varchar2(32767);
    n simple_integer := 0;
    rc sys_refcursor;
begin
    v_stmt := 'select ';
    for idx in p_start..p_end loop
        v_stmt := v_stmt || to_char( p_start + n);
        n := n+1;
        v_stmt := v_stmt || 'res_' || to_char( n);
        if p_start + n < p_end then 
            v_stmt := v_stmt || ',';
        end if;
    end loop;
    v_stmt := v_stmt || ' from dual';
    open rc for v_stmt;
    return rc;
end;
```

Comment: this function return `<Cursor>` after call `select get_numbers (2,5) from dual`. How can I get data from this?